# JavaScript doesn't always work in Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, qualtrics, jchartfx

I am finalizing the coding of a survey on Qualtrics which uses a lot of JavaScript. Unfortunately, for the most important question of my survey, JavaScript does not work [EDIT: does not load] when the question is not in first position in the survey. Yet, I need to ask other questions before as the graphs displayed on this question depend on previous answers.

It is very frustrating to see the code work [here](https://login.qualtrics.com/jfe/preview/SV_6nXCryeTrAMgyMd), when the question is in the first position inside the survey (one can see 5 graphs with blue bars, even if it takes some time for the data to load - ~15 seconds); but the graphs do not display anymore [there](https://login.qualtrics.com/jfe/preview/SV_8e6YtBw4ViXewvP), when I place the question in the second position (to see the absence of graphs, one thus have to answer the first question and click the button next).

FYI, I use jQuery and a a plotting library: jChartFX.

Does anyone have an idea on what could cause this?

[EDIT]: Here is my JavaScript code (excluding headers that load the libraries). It should be embedded in the headers of the HTML:

```
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
        $j(document).ready(function($j){    

            $j.ajax({
                url:'https://login.qualtrics.com/WRQualtricsControlPanel/File.php?F=F_6yFft59YgdvIHfT', 
                success: function(data){
                    var actuelle, rawlsien, utilitarien; 
                    var donnees_rawlsien, donnees_actuelle, donnees_utilitarien;
                    var prefere, egalitaire, actuelle, rawlsien, utilitarien;   
                    var donnees_prefere, donnees_egalitaire; //, donnees_rawlsien, donnees_actuelle, donnees_utilitarien;
                    var donnees = {"utilitarien":donnees_utilitarien,"rawlsien":donnees_rawlsien,"egalitaire":donnees_egalitaire,"actuelle":donnees_actuelle,"prefere":donnees_prefere};
                    prefere = new cfx.Chart();
                    actuelle = new cfx.Chart();
                    egalitaire = new cfx.Chart();
                    rawlsien = new cfx.Chart();
                    utilitarien = new cfx.Chart();
                    donnees_egalitaire = new Array(2);
                    donnees_egalitaire[0] = {x: 0, y: 1800}
                    donnees_egalitaire[1] = {x: 1, y: 1800}
                    donnees_prefere = new Array(2);
                    donnees_prefere[0] = {x: 0, y: 1800}
                    donnees_prefere[1] = {x: 1, y: 1800}
                    var out = charge(data);        
                    donnees_actuelle = out[0];
                    donnees_utilitarien = out[1];
                    donnees_rawlsien = out[2];
                    draw(utilitarien,"utilitarien", donnees_utilitarien);
                    draw(rawlsien,"rawlsien", donnees_rawlsien);
                    draw(actuelle,"actuelle", donnees_actuelle);
                    draw(egalitaire,"egalitaire", donnees_egalitaire);
                    draw(prefere,"prefere", donnees_prefere);   
                },
                error: function(){ 
                    alert('Fail of data loading: utilitarien');
                    donnees_utilitarien = new Array(2);
                    donnees_utilitarien[0] = {x: 0, y: 1800}
                    donnees_utilitarien[1] = {x: 1, revenu: 1800}
                }
            });

            function charge(texte) {
                var dat=texte;
                var tab=dat.split('\n');
                var donnees_actuelle = new Array(100);
                var donnees_utilitarien = new Array(100);
                var donnees_rawlsien = new Array(100);
                for (var i = 0; i<10; i++) {
                    donnees_actuelle[i] = {x:i, y:parseInt(tab[0].split('\t')[0])}
                    donnees_utilitarien[i] =  {x:i, y:parseInt(tab[0].split('\t')[1])}
                    donnees_rawlsien[i] =  {x:i, y:parseInt(tab[0].split('\t')[2])}
                } (...)
                    donnees_actuelle[99] = {x:i, y:parseInt(tab[7].split('\t')[0])}
                    donnees_utilitarien[99] =  {x:i, y:parseInt(tab[7].split('\t')[1])}
                    donnees_rawlsien[99] =  {x:i, y:parseInt(tab[7].split('\t')[2])}
                    var out = new Array(3);
                    out[0] = donnees_actuelle;
                    out[1] = donnees_utilitarien;
                    out[2] = donnees_rawlsien;
                    return out;
            }

            function draw(graph, name, donnees) {   
                graph.setGallery(cfx.Gallery.Bar);

                graph.getAllSeries().setVolume(100);
                var axeY = new cfx.FieldMap();
                axeY.setName("y");
                axeY.setUsage(cfx.FieldUsage.Value);
                graph.getDataSourceSettings().getFields().add(axeY);
                graph.setDataSource(donnees);           
                graph.getAxisY().setMax(12000);
                graph.getAxisX().setVisible(false);
                graph.getAxisY().setStep(1000);
                graph.setBackColor('#00FFFFFF');
                var titreX, titreY;
                titreY = new cfx.TitleDockable();            
                titreY.setText("niveau de vie (€/mois)");
                titreY.setTextColor("#57ACDA");
                graph.getAxisY().setTitle(titreY);
                graph.getLegendBox().setDock(cfx.DockArea.Top);
                graph.getSeries().getItem(0).setText("Niveau de vie des français (en €/mois)");
                graph.getSeries().getItem(0).setColor("#FF0000");
                graph.getLegendBox().setTextColor("#FF0000");
                graph.getLegendBox().setMarginX(250);


                var divHolder = document.getElementById(name);
                graph.create(divHolder);
            }
    });         

});
```

Comment: Could you post the code you are using to generate this in each place? Is it identical or similar?

Comment: I can say that based on a quick search, I'm not seeing the script included on the link that isn't working.

Comment: Wow, I went to the not working survey in Qualtrics to copy/paste you the code (it was there), I retried... and it worked fine. I have just retried a second time... and it does not work anymore XD I have edited my question to give you the code.

Comment: You are right, the Javacsript simply does not show up in the non working case. Otherwise, it is embedded in the main HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Now, it works fine, thanks to the help of Qualtrics support. However, I have not understood what was causing the problem. It seems to work now because the survey is distributed. The bug was only present in the preview mode.